# CarrierWave and MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, carrierwave

How would you install carrierwave and mysql together, I can't find anything in the documentation.  The only way I can see is to install paperclip, then migrate to carrierwave.

**UPDATE:** To be more specific, store the image in a BLOB in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you include RMagick, you can use the to_blob method that it provides: http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#to_blob

Comment: I am still debating on keeping it in a database or in a file system, but i will keep this in mind.

Comment: I would vote against it: A database is designed for run queries on it. You can not run a query against binary blob data. It slows down the application and your backups sizes will grow immense. The only benefit you get is kind of higher referential integrity, but if you store the files on a non public s3 this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What problems are you encountering?

You need to have both carrierwave and mysql in your gemfile and bundled - did you follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Follow the intructions to create uploader, create a migration to add an image string to your model and you'll be all fine.

Comment: Please see update, it is not installing both Gems it (as I can do that) is to store the image in a BLOB in the database as can be done in PHP (see http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql)

Comment: ah right, that bit was kind of vital - no experience with that I'm afraid. Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: Yeah, that is vital...without the update I get where you are coming from, and it is easy...add the mysql and carrierwave to the gem file, run bundle install follow tutorial or railscast episode.

Comment: I'd expect to see a database storage option in https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/tree/master/lib/carrierwave/storage if it was functionality already built into Carrierwave

Comment: I think i read a bit wrong, I am going to handle the file uploads myself...I found this tutorial here (http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=4642) that I am going to try and adapt to Rails 3.